# Placing youtube widget inside jquery ui tabs, not loading videos on IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, embed

I am trying to place a youtube widget given by youtube inside jquery UI tabs. The widget works fine with all browsers when I place the widget outside the tab divs as I have shown here. But the same embed code is not loading the youtube Video thumbnails and not showing the title of the video properly in IE6,7 and firefox when I place them inside the tab divs.
Please Help

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en"> 
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Integration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.flash.js"></script>

    <script>

$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
    </head>
   <body >
   <div class="demo">

    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">  Follow us on Foursquare </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Watch our videos on YouTube </a></li>

                    </ul>


<div id="tabs-1">
                <!-- a foursquare widget which works--->
<div id="tabs-2" >
     <!--placing it inside -->
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=**YOURCHANNEL**&amp;synd=open&amp;w=400&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js">
    </script>
    </div> 
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
     <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
       <!--placing it outside -->
    <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=**YOURCHANNEL**&amp;synd=open&amp;w=400&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js">
    </script>

      </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using the iframe option on youtube.  Try that.  I'm still working on the css formatting of it but it does work.  Let me know if you get that part figured out. See this example: http://www.curiouscountrycreations.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=186